# How to print the lead of A* algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

-I wrote a program to find the shortest path from a source node to a target node. Everything is fine, the program found the shortest path. But i have a problem, that is not able to print or get each node in the path. I tried many ways but no result. Hope anyone can help me, thanks everyone.

**///////////////////////////////**

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef struct Node
{
    int vertex;
    int g;
    int h;
    int f;
    Node* parent;
    Node(int vertex)
    {
        this->vertex = vertex;
        this->g = 0;
        this->h = 0;
        this->f = 0;
        this->parent=NULL;
    }

    Node(int vertex,int g, int h, int f,Node*parent)
    {
        this->vertex = vertex;
        this->g      = g;
        this->h      = h;
        this->f      = f;
        this->parent = parent;
    }
}Node;

struct Edge
{
    int source;
    int dest;
    int g;
    int h;
};

struct comp
{
    bool operator()(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) const {
        return lhs->f < rhs->f;
    }
};

std::vector<Node*>openList;
std::vector<Node*>closeList;

Node* startPos;
Node* endPos;
static const int WeightW = 10;

class Graph
{
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<Edge>>adjlist;
    Graph(const std::vector<Edge>& edges, int N)
    {
        adjlist.resize(N);
        for (auto &edge:edges)
        {
            adjlist[edge.source].push_back(edge);
        }
    }
};

int isContains(std::vector<Node*>* Nodelist, int vertex);
void printPath(Node*node);
void findShortestPath(const Graph& grap,Node* start,Node* end, int N)
{
    Node* node;
    openList.push_back(start);
    while (openList.size()>0)
    {
        node = openList[0];
        closeList.push_back(node);
        openList.erase(openList.begin());
        std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
        int u = node->vertex;   
        std::cout << "V: " << u << " g :" << node->g << std::endl;
        std::cout << "continous" << std::endl;
        
        for (auto v : grap.adjlist[u])
        {
           if (v.dest == end->vertex)
           {
             std::cout << "FindNode " << v.dest << std::endl;
             printPath(node);
             return;
           }
           if (isContains(&closeList, v.dest) == -1)
           {
                if (isContains(&openList, v.dest) == -1)
                {
                    int vertex = v.dest;
                    std::cout <<"V: "<< vertex << std::endl;                
                    int h = v.h;
                    int currentg = node->g + v.g;
                    int f = currentg + h;
                    std::cout <<"vertext: "<<vertex<< " h: " << h << " g: " << currentg << " f: " << f  << std::endl;               
                    Node* newNode = new Node(vertex, currentg, h, f,node->parent);
                    openList.push_back(newNode);        
                }
            }               
        }   
        std::cout<<"Close: ";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < closeList.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << closeList[i]->vertex << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        sort(openList.begin(), openList.end(),comp());
        std::cout << "Open: ";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < openList.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << openList[i]->vertex << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void printPath(Node* node)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    if (node->parent != NULL)
        printPath(node->parent);
    std::cout << node->vertex << " ";
}
int isContains(std::vector<Node*>* Nodelist,int vertex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Nodelist->size(); i++)
    {
        if (Nodelist->at(i)->vertex== vertex)
        {
            
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    //{Node,Node,G,H}
    //Firt   Node 
    //second Node
    //G is  the movement cost to move from the starting point to a given square on the grid
    // following the path generated to get there
    //H is the estimated movement cost to move from that given square on the grid to the final destination

    std::vector<Edge>edges =
    {
        {0,1,5,17},                             
        {0,2,5,13},

        {1,0,5,16},
        {1,3,3,16},
        {1,2,4,13},

        {2,0,5,16},
        {2,1,4,17},
        {2,3,7,16},
        {2,4,7,16},
        {2,7,8,11},

        {3,2,7,13},
        {3,7,11,11},
        {3,10,16,4},
        {3,11,13,7},
        {3,12,14,10},

        {4,2,7,13},
        {4,5,4,20},
        {4,7,5,11},

        {5,4,4,16},
        {5,6,9,17},
        
        {6,5,9,20},
        {6,13,12,7},

        {7,3,11,16},
        {7,4,5,16},
        {7,8,3,10},

        {8,7,3,11},
        {8,9,4,8},

        {9,8,4,10},
        {9,13,3,7},
        {9,15,8,0},

        {10,3,16,16},
        {10,11,5,7},
        {10,13,7,7},
        {10,15,4,0},

        {11,3,13,16},
        {11,10,5,4},
        {11,12,9,10},
        {11,14,4,5},

        {12,3,14,16},
        {12,11,9,7},
        {12,14,5,5},

        {13,9,3,8},
        {13,10,7,4},
        {13,15,7,0},

        {14,11,4,7},
        {14,12,5,10},

        {15,9,8,8},
        {15,10,4,4},
        {15,13,7,7},
    };

    int n = edges.size();
    Graph grap(edges, n);
    //std::cout << h << std::endl;
    Node* start = new Node(0);
    Node* end   = new Node(15);
    findShortestPath(grap, start, end, n);
    //Astar astar;
    //Node* startPos = new Node(5, 1);
    //Node* endPos = new Node(1, 8);

    //astar.printMap();
    //astar.search(startPos, endPos);
    //cout << endl;
    //astar.printMap();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry, 250+ lines are a bit too much for me to debug. Are you saving the shortest path somewhere? Nothing is returned by the function but I can see two global variables, is it one of them?

Comment: @dungtonluong I would recommend you 1) cleaning up the code a bit, removing code that is commented out, and maybe working with a smaller `edges` vector, and, most importantly, 2) pointing to the code that is not working and explain the problem a bit clearer; is `findShortestPath` not working as expected? What is the expected output and the current output? I think it may also help to divide the code in two parts: find the shortest path and printing it; find the shortest path could return a vector of nodes (or node pointers).

Comment: sorry, as this is my first time posting here, I tried to keep the code as simple as possible. I thought shortening the code would confuse people. I'm sorry about that.I found a solution to this problem, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't find the shortest path. It gives the wrong output. (you're on the right track though)

I will assume you are trying to find the shortest path by using BFS. Let's take a look at line 113:

```
    sort(openList.begin(), openList.end(),comp());
```

Here you're sorting your BFS queue (vector in your case) and thus destroying the right order.

Delete that line.

Congrats, now your program finds the shortest path!

Next, as I understand, for each node you branch into, you remember which node you came from in order to backtrack the path once you reach the destination or final node.

In line 102:

```
Node* newNode = new Node(vertex, currentg, h, f,node->parent);
```

you are assigning the new node's grandparent instead of parent. Change that line to

```
Node* newNode = new Node(vertex, currentg, h, f,node);
```

Now your `printPath` function works properly and prints the right path. (just add the target node)

Anyways, your code has a lot of space for improvements. [Check out other implementations online](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-paths-given-source-destination-using-bfs/) and try to see if you can code it as short and clean for practice. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, have a nice day. You are correct, the program outputs the lead exactly as I expected. I made a mistake which is too simple. Most people use the algorithm. This math is on a 2d map and I can't find anyone using the nodes that are linked together, except for dijkstra's algorithm. So I researched and rewrote it myself. I understand how to do it but I don't understand because after it can track each node by just adding its parent to each node, can you explain it to me?

Comment: It works because you are "equally" spreading from the start node visiting the nodes with distance 1 first, then the nodes with distance 2 and so on. That means you will always visit the node with a shorter path before the one with a longer path. So when you reach the target node for the first time, you will know that this is the shortest path and that you can just go back to where you came from, node by node (that is why your variable `parent` saves the node you came from).